# Electron windows is blank on load

Tags: php, electron

I want to embed some php server side code inside an electron app. I've found an interesting way to make php work inside my app, but I have a small problem when the app start. In fact the main window is blank until I refresh it. Is it possible to refresh the page to solve this issue?

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const electron = require('electron');
const Menu = electron.Menu;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const os = require('os');
// PHP SERVER CREATION /////
const PHPServer = require('php-server-manager');
var php = 'php';
// if(os.platform === 'win32' && os.arch === 'ia32'){
//    php = path.resolve(__dirname)+'/php/x86/php.exe';
// }
// if(os.platform === 'win32' && os.arch === 'x64'){
//    php = path.resolve(__dirname)+'/php/x64/php.exe';
// }
const server = new PHPServer({
  php: php,
  directory: path.resolve(__dirname)+'/',
  directives: {
      display_errors: 1,
      expose_php: 0
  }
});
app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow();
  server.run();
  mainWindow.reload();
  // if (os.platform === 'darwin') {
  // }
});

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 620, });
  mainWindow.center();
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php');
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // PHP SERVER QUIT
      server.close();
      mainWindow = null;
    });
  }
  app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (os.platform !== 'darwin') {
      // PHP SERVER QUIT
      server.close();
      app.quit();
    }
  });
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

After some research, I've found a way to load the window contents, the issue of the blank window is related to the `script` parameter of the php server manager module. After I've pointed it to the index.php that is the router of my app, the content is loaded, but now I've two console errors:

> jquery.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1

and

> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

If anyone knows how to fix these, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to hook your server start off the `ready-to-show` event.

```
mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
   server.run();
   mainWindow.show()
})
```

Comment: I will try with your suggestion.

Comment: It's not working. If i set the server to run when the main window is ready to show, it will not run.

Comment: @dwpu - start it earlier?

Comment: @dwpu - no, I'm just suggesting something that is easy to try. Get the server up and running and THEN open show the window.